# Java Class Property

Tags: java, class, properties, get, set

Yesterday I asked a question and got what I'm looking for.. sort of. I still don't know how to implement it into my code. So long story short I had a Booking Class which was extending a Customer Class. I was told to remove the "Extend" and include Customer as a property of Booking Class... which makes sense. I encapsulated the Customer field to get the 'Set' and 'Get' of the field. Now I still don't know how to get the Customer from the Customer class and load it in the Booking Form since I removed the 'Extend'. Really appreciate for someone to help me. Thanks

```
public class Booking implements Serializable{

    private String flighttime;
    private String flightlocation;
    private String flightfee;
    private boolean car;
    private boolean insurance;
    private Customer customer;

    /**
     * @return the flighttime
     */
    public String getFlighttime() {
        return flighttime;
    }

    /**
     * @param flighttime the flighttime to set
     */
    public void setFlighttime(String flighttime) {
        this.flighttime = flighttime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the flightlocation
     */
    public String getFlightlocation() {
        return flightlocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param flightlocation the flightlocation to set
     */
    public void setFlightlocation(String flightlocation) {
        this.flightlocation = flightlocation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the flightfee
     */
    public String getFlightfee() {
        return flightfee;
    }

    /**
     * @param flightfee the flightfee to set
     */
    public void setFlightfee(String flightfee) {
        this.flightfee = flightfee;
    }

    /**
     * @return the car
     */
    public boolean getCar() {
        return isCar();
    }

    /**
     * @param car the car to set
     */
    public void setCar(boolean car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    /**
     * @return the car
     */
    public boolean isCar() {
        return car;
    }

    /**
     * @return the insurance
     */
    public boolean isInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }

    /**
     * @param insurance the insurance to set
     */
    public void setInsurance(boolean insurance) {
        this.insurance = insurance;
    }

    public boolean getInsurance() {
        return isInsurance();
    }

    /**
     * @return the customer
     */
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    /**
     * @param customer the customer to set
     */
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

}
```

```
public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

    private String passportID;
    private String consultantname;
    private String consultantsurname;
    private String consulid;


    /**
     * @return the passaprtID
     */
    public String getPassportID() {
        return passportID;
    }

    /**
     * @param passportID the passaprtID to set
     */
    public void setPassportID(String passportID) {
        this.passportID = passportID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the consultantname
     */
    public String getConsultantname() {
        return consultantname;
    }

    /**
     * @param consultantname the consultantname to set
     */
    public void setConsultantname(String consultantname) {
        this.consultantname = consultantname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the consultantsurname
     */
    public String getConsultantsurname() {
        return consultantsurname;
    }

    /**
     * @param consultantsurname the consultantsurname to set
     */
    public void setConsultantsurname(String consultantsurname) {
        this.consultantsurname = consultantsurname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the consulid
     */
    public String getConsulid() {
        return consulid;
    }

    /**
     * @param consulid the consulid to set
     */
    public void setConsulid(String consulid) {
        this.consulid = consulid;
    }

}
```

```
public class BookingFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form BookingFrame
     */
    public BookingFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

     private void loadCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Customer customerfile = null;
        try {

            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Customers/");
            int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(file)
                );

                customerfile = (Customer) in.readObject();

                custnameTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonName());
                custsurnameTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonSurname());
                custidTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonID());
                consnameTF.setText(customerfile.getConsultantname());
                conssurnameTF.setText(customerfile.getConsultantsurname());
                considTF.setText(customerfile.getConsulid());

                in.close();

            } else {
                throw new CancelException("Canceled Operation");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading File" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading Class");
        } catch (CancelException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Canceled Loading Customer",
                    "Canceled", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                            

    private void savebookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Booking customerbooking = new Booking();

        try {
            if (custnameTF.getText().equals("")) {
                throw new EmptyField("Please Insert Customer");
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Bookings/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                customerbooking.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
                customerbooking.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
                customerbooking.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));
                customerbooking.setConsultantname(consnameTF.getText());
                customerbooking.setConsultantsurname((conssurnameTF.getText()));
                customerbooking.setConsulid(considTF.getText());
                customerbooking.setFlightlocation(locationCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlighttime(timeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlightfee(feeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setCar(carRB.isSelected());
                customerbooking.setInsurance(insuranceRB.isSelected());

                oos.writeObject(customerbooking);
                oos.close();
                fos.close();

                custnameTF.setText("");
                custsurnameTF.setText("");
                custidTF.setText("");
                considTF.setText("");
                consnameTF.setText("");
                conssurnameTF.setText("");
                locationCB.setSelectedItem("");
                timeCB.setSelectedItem("");
                feeCB.setSelectedItem("");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking was Saved Successfully!",
                        "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking could not be Saved!",
                    "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (EmptyField ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Insert Customer",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        dispose();

    }                                                 

    private void custnameTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void custidTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void loadbookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Booking bookingfile = null;
        try {

            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Bookings/");
            int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(file)
                );

                bookingfile = (Booking) in.readObject();

                custnameTF.setText(bookingfile.getPersonName());
                custsurnameTF.setText(bookingfile.getPersonSurname());
                custidTF.setText(bookingfile.getPersonID());
                consnameTF.setText(bookingfile.getConsultantname());
                conssurnameTF.setText(bookingfile.getConsultantsurname());
                considTF.setText(bookingfile.getConsulid());
                locationCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlightlocation());
                timeCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlighttime());
                feeCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlightfee());
                carRB.setSelected(bookingfile.getCar());
                insuranceRB.setSelected(bookingfile.getInsurance());

                in.close();

            } else {
                throw new CancelException("Canceled Operation");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading File" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading Class");
        } catch (CancelException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Canceled Loading Booking",
                    "Canceled", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                                 

    private void createCustbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        CustomerFrame nc = new CustomerFrame();
        nc.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what you mean

- If you want to create a new booking, just load customer information like the method **loadCustomerActionPerformed()** do.
- If you want to load information of customer from a Booking instance you saved in file. When you get object Booking from the file. You just need to call get methods to get Customer object inside your Booking object

  ```
  private void loadbookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
  Booking bookingfile = null;
  try {

      final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Bookings/");
      int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

          File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
          ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                  new FileInputStream(file)
          );

          bookingfile = (Booking) in.readObject();

          Customer customer = bookingfile.getCustomer();
          custnameTF.setText(customer.getPersonName());
          custsurnameTF.setText(customer.getPersonSurname());
          custidTF.setText(customer.getPersonID());
          consnameTF.setText(customer.getConsultantname());
          conssurnameTF.setText(customer.getConsultantsurname());

          considTF.setText(bookingfile.getConsulid());
          locationCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlightlocation());
          timeCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlighttime());
          feeCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlightfee());
          carRB.setSelected(bookingfile.getCar());
          insuranceRB.setSelected(bookingfile.getInsurance());

          in.close();

      } else {
          throw new CancelException("Canceled Operation");
      }

  } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Error Loading File" + ex.getMessage());
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println("Error Loading Class");
  } catch (CancelException ex) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Canceled Loading Booking",
              "Canceled", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
  ```

  }
- One more thing, when you save the Booking object, you also need to pack you customer information into a Customer instance.

  ```
  private void savebookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
  Booking customerbooking = new Booking();

  try {
      if (custnameTF.getText().equals("")) {
          throw new EmptyField("Please Insert Customer");
      } else {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Bookings/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

          Customer customer = new Customer();
          customer.setPersonName(custnameTF.getText());
          customer.setPersonSurname(custsurnameTF.getText());
          customer.setPersonID(custidTF.getText());
          customer.setConsultantname(custsurnameTF.getText());
          customer.setConsultantsurname(conssurnameTF.getText());
          customer.setConsulid(considTF.getText());
          customerbooking.setCustomer(customer);

          customerbooking.setFlightlocation(locationCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
          customerbooking.setFlighttime(timeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
          customerbooking.setFlightfee(feeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
          customerbooking.setCar(carRB.isSelected());
          customerbooking.setInsurance(insuranceRB.isSelected());

          oos.writeObject(customerbooking);
          oos.close();
          fos.close();

          custnameTF.setText("");
          custsurnameTF.setText("");
          custidTF.setText("");
          considTF.setText("");
          consnameTF.setText("");
          conssurnameTF.setText("");
          locationCB.setSelectedItem("");
          timeCB.setSelectedItem("");
          feeCB.setSelectedItem("");

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking was Saved Successfully!",
                  "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      }

  } catch (IOException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking could not be Saved!",
              "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  } catch (EmptyField ex) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Insert Customer",
              "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }

  dispose();
  ```

  }
- I also see you lack of passportID here.

Comment: The thing is that when I removed the Extend Customer from the Booking Class I cant get a link between the classes. I am having errors in the setPersonName etc... since I removed the Extend and the classes are no longer linked.

Comment: Have you rechecked your import for classes? Since you removed extend, the classes must need to organize import again. This may cause your problem.

Comment: How can I check please? Thanks

Comment: You go to Source-->Organize Import or use combined key Ctrl + Shift + O.